# JQuery get all data attributes from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a long dynamically generated list each with the same class identifier and a data attribute similar to the code below:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list" data-id="123">One</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="124">Two</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="125">Three</li>
    <li class="list" data-id="126">Four</li>
    .....etc
</ul>
```

what I am trying to achieve is to get all the `data-id` values and format them in as follows:

```
123|124|125|126....etc
```

this would be then passed to a page via ajax and the id's checked for existence in a database.

```
var delimited_data="";
$('.list').each(function(){
    delimited_data+=$(this).data('id')+"|";
});
console.log(delimited_data);
```

The reason I am asking this question is that I am working on a live system that automatically deploys items in the list columns to different users after 10 mins. I just need to be sure that the code is going the right way :)

I also need to check that is there are no `.list` classes on the page (ie - no way to do the query) whether `delimited_data` will be totally empty which I am pretty sure it would be.

Is there a better way than using `.each()` in this case as I find it can be rather slow baring in mind that the above function will be run every 30 seconds.

Comment: To check existence of `.list`, run a check on the length of `.list`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `.map` to return an array:

```
var dataList = $(".list").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("id");
}).get();

console.log(dataList.join("|"));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RPpXu/

Comment: this seems quite a neat way of doing this - not used .map() before )

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
var array = [];

$('li.list').each(function() {
  array.push($(this).data('id'));
})

var joined = array.join('|');
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question but this is what i ended up on this page in search for and though it would help someone else :-)

```
var arrayOfObj = $('input').map(function() {

  return {
            name : $(this).attr('name'),
            data : $(this).data('options'),
            value : $(this).val(),
            id : $(this).attr('id')
         }

}).get();
console.log(arrayOfObj)
```

This returns an array of objects that mimics the input 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

as an update for @tymeJV answer for new versions of JavaScript you can use `.map((index, elem) => return value)` like this:

```
let result = $(".list").map((index, elem) => elem.dataset.id).get().join('|');
```