# jQuery each and map to a new object based on data-attribute

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to extract all IDs from multiple elements based on data-attribute.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item" data-element='{"id":1, "name":"John"}'>John</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"data-element='{"id":2, "name":"Peter"}'>Peter</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and javascript:

```
var result = [];
$('[data-element]').each(function() {
    result = $(this).data('element');
}); 

$.map(result, function( val, i ) {
   console.log(val)
});
```

The problem is that I only get the last element. Console log shows 2 Peter.

What I would like to be the final result is all id's as well as names extracted in form of an array like:

```
id = [1,2]
name = ['John', 'Peter']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery get all data attributes from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346640/jquery-get-all-data-attributes-from-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with empty arrays and push each value into corresponding array within one loop. You seem to be over complicating it

```js
var arrObj={ id:[], name:[] };

$('[data-element]').each(function() {
   var data = $(this).data('element');
   arrObj.id.push(data.id);
   arrObj.name.push(data.name);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrObj,null,' '))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item" data-element='{"id":1, "name":"John"}'>John</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"data-element='{"id":2, "name":"Peter"}'>Peter</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you had a lot of properties and wanted each property value in an array you could run another internal loop over the properties instead of manually writing each push, something like:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
   arrObj[key].push(value);
})
```

Comment: Thank you perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `map` **inside** the `each` function you have:

```js
var result = [];
var id = [];
var name = [];
$('[data-element]').each(function() {
  result = $(this).data('element');
  
  id[id.length] = result.id;
  name[name.length] = result.name;
  
  $.map(result, function( val, i ) {
    console.log(val)
  });
  
});

console.log(id)
console.log(name)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item" data-element='{"id":1, "name":"John"}'>John</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"data-element='{"id":2, "name":"Peter"}'>Peter</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise - the `each` function walk over all your elements, and when the loop is done - the value in `result` is the value of the last element that has `[data-element]` attribute (and you map the function to that result).

> Based on what you want to get - I'm not sure you even need the `map` function there. Check the usage of `result.id` and `result.name` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an empty array to the value of `$(this).data('element')` on every iteration of your forEach loop. So, the last iteration will always be the value of `result` when you evaluate it. Use the Array methods to add items to the array instead of setting it; so instead of `result = $(this).data('element');` it should be `result.push($(this).data('element'));`